# cannot import name 'LayerNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, layer, dense-rank

I am trying to build a ANN model using Tensorflow library on Spyder. Afte ı set my training and test data, ı imported the keras library as seen below

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

But the prcocess did not finished normally.I tookthe same error-> cannnot import name 'LayerNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization'

I am using the following versions Spyder 4.2.5 tensorflow 2.7

Comment: Please try importing `LayerNormalization` using `from tensorflow.keras.layers import LayerNormalization`. Let us know if issue still persists.

Comment: It did not worked. I took the error "ImportError: cannot import name 'LayerNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization' (C:\...\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\normalization\__init__.py)"

Comment: from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LayerNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

Comment: Ok, Could you please tell me how you installed tensorflow and which Python version are you using?

Comment: Hello again, I installed it from anaconda individiual edition. Tensorflow installaion was done in Anaconda interface in Enviromets section. PS: pyhton verison is 3.8.8

Answer (score 0):

Please create a new virtual environment in `ananconda` to install `TensorFlow`:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow   #"tf" is the name for your TensorFlow environment
conda activate tf         # to activate the virtual environment

pip install tensorflow  # install tensorlfow in that environment
```

Select the same `"tf"` environment in `anaconda navigator` and install `Spyder` to launch and type below code to check if `TensorFlow` installed properly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Now please try again executing your code in this `Spyder IDE`.